# Clip slope raster for values outside of percent grade range

Tags: clip, raster-calculator

I have a slope raster, but I would like to remove values (or make them no data value shading) outside a range which makes them too steep. I tried looking at the raster calculator, and I am not sure how to use it if it can. I keep getting an invalid expression.

An example is a slope percent grade raster, anything over 60% grade is not safe, so I would like to finish with a raster showing this remaining white/gray area.

How would I do this and what tools are needed?

The projection is in UTM meters, but I would also like to do degrees, however, in 4326 the percent grade slope values are extremely high and hard to interpret. So I am starting with just UTM meters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the processing toolbox raster calculator in QGIS 3.16.15 works but not the calculator in the menu bar. I got valid expressions from this.